# USB HOST not displaying text (Nexus 6p and stm32)

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, host, stm32

I am trying to write something to serial /dev/ttyACM0 ( STM32).
Andorid see STM32 as /dev/bus/usb/001/002.

I have rooted phone Nexus 6p and Stm32 connected via usb.

I saw Google USB HOST example so I try do the same.

I have connection with stm and granted permissions

```
UsbDeviceConnection connection = mManager.openDevice(mdevice);



String simpleText = "a";
    byte[] DATA = simpleText.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    int TIMEOUT = 10;
```

And trying this

```
 UsbEndpoint endpoint = mdevice.getInterface(0).getEndpoint(0);

 connection.claimInterface(mdevice.getInterface(0), true);
connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, DATA, DATA.length, TIMEOUT);
```

And also have small program in my Stm for reading from serial

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "LCD_DISCO_L476VG.h"

LCD_DISCO_L476VG lcd;
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX); 

DigitalOut led_green(LED1);

char c;
uint8_t buff[1];

int main() {
   lcd.Clear();
   while(1) {
       if(pc.readable()) {
           buff[0] = pc.getc();
lcd.DisplayString(buff);
   }
}
}
```

But nothing is displaying in STm32 lcd.

Permissions:

```
permission granted for device UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/002,mVendorId=1155,mProductId=14155,mClass=239,mSubclass=2,mProtocol=1,mManufacturerName=STMicroelectronics,mProductName=STM32 STLink,mVersion=2.0,mSerialNumber=066FFF485649785087165544,mConfigurations=[
                                                                         UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=128,mMaxPower=150,mInterfaces=[
                                                                         UsbInterface[mId=0,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=ST-Link Debug,mClass=255,mSubclass=255,mProtocol=255,mEndpoints=[
                                                                         UsbEndpoint[mAddress=129,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=0]
                                                                         UsbEndpoint[mAddress=1,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=0]
                                                                         UsbEndpoint[mAddress=130,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=32,mInterval=0]]
                                                                         UsbInterface[mId=1,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=ST-Link mass storage,mClass=8,mSubclass=6,mProtocol=80,mEndpoints=[
                                                                         UsbEndpoint[mAddress=131,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=0]
                                                                         UsbEndpoint[mAddress=3,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=0]]
                                                                         UsbInterface[mId=2,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=ST-Link VCP Ctr,mClass=2,mSubclass=2,mProtocol=1,mEndpoints=[
                                                                         UsbEndpoint[mAddress=132,mAttributes=3,mMaxPacketSize=2,mInterval=255]]
                                                                         UsbInterface[mId=3,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=ST-Link VCP Dat,mClass=10,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mEndpoints=[
                                                                         UsbEndpoint[mAddress=5,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=8,mInterval=0]
                                                                         UsbEndpoint[mAddress=133,mAttributes=2,mMaxPacketSize=16,mInterval=0]]]]
```

Meybe this is wrong?

```
  UsbEndpoint endpoint = mdevice.getInterface(0).getEndpoint(0);
```

Any advice? : )

Comment: You probably meant `/dev/ttyACM0` instead of `/dev/ACM0`.

Comment: Yea edited. But still ...